# Twig i18n : Unexpected tag name "trans"

Tags: php, internationalization, twig, silex

I'm trying to do some i18n on some Twig templates. The relevant code in index.php is as follows :

```
// Twig
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../src/views',
));
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($app['twig.loader.filesystem']);
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());

// User Controller Service Provider for SimpleUser
$app->register($u = new SimpleUser\UserServiceProvider());
$app['twig.loader.filesystem']->addPath(__DIR__.'/../src/views/user','user');
$app['user.controller']->setLayoutTemplate('layout.twig');
$app->mount('/silex-ror/user', $u);
```

Then, in the twig template being rendered I wrote :

```
<h1>{% trans %}List users{% endtrans %}</h1>
```

But I get an error :

```
Unexpected tag name "trans"
```

Since I don't get any error when adding the extension, I assume it's simply being completely ignored when I try to render the template, but I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question, but it seems that I solved it so I'd like to share the solution here. However I'm still not a 100% sure how this works :

    $app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
        $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());
        return $twig;
    }));

It looks like my previous code was simply not adding the extension to the proper environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the Translation Provider before:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
  'locale_fallbacks' => array('en'),
));
```

and then register Twig:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
  'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../src/views',
));
```

there is no need to register the Twig i18n extension!

See also [Silex TranslationServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/translation.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, but this doesn't give me access to functions like 'plural', for example...

Comment: You can use the `transchoice` tag or the `transchoice()` filter for pluralization or not? See [Translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Comment: Yes. That works. Thanks a bunch for your help ! I have to admit I am a bit confused by the existence of both the i18n Twig extension and the Silex Translation Service Provider.